# Does AWS Aurora MySQL not support encrypted binary log replication with RDS MySQL master?

Tags: mysql, replication, amazon-rds, aws, aws-aurora

Trying to setup replication between an RDS MySQL (5.6) master with an Aurora MySQL (also 5.6) replica cluster in the same region via binary log replication for a work project. However, this doesn't seem to work if I require SSL encryption for the replication user I created on the MySQL master when I do the following:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'repl_user'@'<domain_name>' REQUIRE SSL;
```

Then when I initiate the replication process by running this query on the Aurora replica cluster's instance

```
CALL mysql.rds_set_external_master ('<my db host name>', 3306,
    'repl_user', '<password>', 'mysql-test-cluster', 107, 1); <-- maybe passing 1 is not supported?
```

I get an error that looks like this

```
"ERROR 1200 (HY000): The server is not configured as slave; fix in config file or with CHANGE MASTER TO"
```

Note, replication works perfectly fine as long as I don't require SSL and pass in 0 instead for ssl_encryption parameter in mysql.rds_set_external_master query

I have been following the [official public docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Replication.MySQL.html) and I only see an example of encrypted replication being done between an external MySQL database and an Aurora MySQL cluster.

Originally I thought this was just for brevity, but now I am wondering if encrypted binary log replication is simply just not supported between RDS MySQL and Aurora MySQL?